# How to construct arel query with 'and' and 'or' on different tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

2 models: `Dimension` and `DimensionType`

`DimensionType` has_many `:dimensions`

How do I construct a query like this using `arel` or classic `ActiveRecord`:

```
select * from dimension_types dt
inner join dimensions d on d.dimension_type_id=dt.id
where 
(dt.identifier = 'geo' and d.identifier in ('uk','us'))
or 
(dt.identifier = 'unit' and d.identifier in ('bn', 't'))
```

where number of dimensions and dimension types I need to select is dynamic, say:

```
queryArguments = {geo: [:uk, :us], unit: [:t, :bn], x: [:y, :etc]}
```

I'm using Rails 4

Answer (score 0):

You can have in you `DimensionType` model something like this:

```
def self.search params
  params.keys.inject([]) do |result, dt_identifier|
    result += DimensionType.joins(:dimensions).where("dimension_types.identifier", dt_identifier).where(["dimensions.identifier IN (?)", params[dt_identifier]])
  end
end
```

then, you can use it like this:

```
DimensionType.search({geo: [:uk, :us], unit: [:t, :bn], x: [:y, :etc]})
```

Comment: thx, but won't that invoke the query many times? Ideally I'd have just 1 select.